# Why runtime errors are difficult to find than compile-time errors

Tags: java, runtime

According to the java Doc, one advantage of generics is 
Stronger type checks at compile time.
A Java compiler applies strong type checking to generic code and issues errors if the code violates type safety. Fixing compile-time errors is easier than fixing runtime errors, which can be difficult to find.

Why is runtime errors are difficult to find than compile-time errors?

Comment: It's not accurate that "runtime errors are difficult to find". They simply occur at runtime and they're not predictable.

As a programmer, you want to avoid them, or knowing that they might happen and handle them accordingly if you can. Also you *want* the compiler to yell at you if you have problems so you can fix them before running the code.

Comment: Because with compile time errors, all factors of the system are known, where as at runtime there are dynamic things, such as user input, etc

Answer (score 3):

- Because there's no way the compiler accepts to compile invalid code. Whereas you can execute an application for a week, and never actually execute the piece of code that has a bug.
- Because the compiler is very well specified and outputs clear, well-known error messages whereas buggy code can show a whole lot of strange behaviors: from a pixel having the wrong color to an exception, or an inconsistent database.
- Because you compile constantly, and a compilation error thus comes from a code that you just wrote, whereas a runtime error can come from code that has been written by 10 other people, 2 years ago.
- Because, as bearteach says in a comment, the error might come for user input, or the current time, or any kind of dynamic input or environment that is not known anymore while analyzing the bug
- ...

Comment: ... Because you don't want the missile you're programming to have runtime errors.

Answer (score 2):

When you compile your code, you see the compilation errors immediately. The compiler tells you what the errors are.

Runtime errors, on the other hand, can only be discovered when you run the code. Sometimes they cause the application to crash, while other times they just cause undesired behavior. The code might even run for years before you find a runtime error. In order to find runtime errors you have to test and debug your code, which costs time.

Answer (score 1):

The compile time errors are easy to detect because compiler makes the complete structured tree for compilation so its easy to check errors either syntax or logical intelligence because you have to match pattern against code.

While running the code is on execution mode and creates buffer for execution and it gets deleted after program execution. So we need explicit debugging for getting errors at run time. Or we have to use some tools that catch the run time data and prepare the log information for us.

After all we have to modify the code again and recompile again. Its fine for small software but difficult for large software so Its always better to check at compile time error than run time.